# Global variable not working inside switch - javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, switch-statement, global-variables

```
 let visitor;
 const role = req.user.profile;

 // role will be either Admin or Manager

 switch (role) {
   case 'Admin':
     if (req.body.verificationMode === 'online') {
       visitor = {
         name: req.body.name,
         mode: 'online',
       };
     } else {
       visitor = {
         name: req.body.name,
         mode: 'offline'
       };
     }
     break;


   case 'Manager':
     Staff.findOne({
       where: {
         loginId: req.user.id,
       },
     }).then((staffData) => {
       if (req.body.verificationMode === 'online') {
         visitor = {
           name: req.body.name,
           mode: 'online',
         };
       } else {
         visitor = {
           name: req.body.name,
           mode: 'offline',
         };
       }
     });
     break;

 }
 console.log('visitor >>> >> >> >> >>> >>>> >>>> >>>> >>> >>>> >>>', visitor);
```

If i login as **Admin** role, console of visitor having correct data, but if loginned as **Manager** role, console of visitor become **undefined**.

Why this is happening? I am using ES6, so i dont use var.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: you have async code in case of `Manager` which executes after `console.log`. that why visitor is `undefined` in that case.

Comment: @AagamJain is right, your console.log is printed even before the visitor variable is set by the Staff.findOne async statement.

Comment: @MohamedSameer The `.then()` in your code is executed **after** your `console.log()`. So visitor is not set yet.

Comment: @Frost no, `const` and `let` or even ES6 would have absolutely no impact on async code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have async code in case of Manager which executes after console.log. that why visitor is undefined in that case.

use this.

```
 let visitor;
 const role = req.user.profile;
 let callback = function(){
     console.log('visitor >>> >> >> >> >>> >>>> >>>> >>>> >>> >>>> >>>', visitor); 
 }
 // role will be either Admin or Manager



 switch (role) {
   case 'Admin':
     if (req.body.verificationMode === 'online') {
       visitor = {
         name: req.body.name,
         mode: 'online',
       };
     } else {
       visitor = {
         name: req.body.name,
         mode: 'offline'
       };
     }
     callback();
     break;


   case 'Manager':
     Staff.findOne({
       where: {
         loginId: req.user.id,
       },
     }).then((staffData) => {
       if (req.body.verificationMode === 'online') {
         visitor = {
           name: req.body.name,
           mode: 'online',
         };
       } else {
         visitor = {
           name: req.body.name,
           mode: 'offline',
         };
       }
       callback();
     });
     break;

 }
```

moved `console.log` into a function which is called after `visitor` value initialised.

Comment: Thanks its working now, whether is it good to use callback? or async await or promises?